# Как создать HTML-кнопку, которая будет вести себя, как гиперссылка?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я хочу создать HTML-кнопку, которая будет работать, как гиперссылка: при щелчке на кнопке она должна перенаправлять пользователя на определенную страницу. Я хочу, чтобы кнопка была максимально удобной.Также я хотел бы, чтобы в URL не было дополнительных символов или параметров.

Как мне этого добиться?

Сейчас я делаю так:

```
<form method="get" action="/page2">
    <button type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```

Проблема состоит в том, что в [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) и [Internet Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer) в конце URL добавляется знак вопроса. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы дополнительных символов в конец URL не было.

Есть два возможных решения данной проблемы: использование JavaScript и оформление гиперссылки в виде кнопки.

Использование JavaScript:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='/page2'">Continue</button>
```

Но это, конечно же, требует JavaScript, и по этой причине не будет работать для программ чтения экрана.

Цель гиперссылки – перемещение на другую страницу. Поэтому попытка заставить кнопку действовать, как ссылка – неверное решение, то есть использовать гиперссылку и [с помощью стилей сделать ее похожей на кнопку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button) – не верно.

```
<a href="/page2>Continue</a>
```

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/)» [@Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48523/andrew).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HTML

Простой способ сделать с помощью HTML – оформить все в виде `<form>`, где указать целевой URL в качестве атрибута `action`.

```
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Google">
</form>
```

При необходимости, установите CSS-свойство `display: inline;` на форме, чтобы она двигалась вместе с окружающим текстом.

### CSS

Если разрешен CSS, просто используйте `<a>`, оформив гиперссылку, как кнопку с помощью свойства [`appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) и других ([только поддержка Internet Explorer в данный момент (июль 2015) все еще очень слаба](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance)).

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="button">Go to Google</a>


a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}
```

Или выберите одну из множества CSS-библиотек наподобие [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons).

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="btn btn-default">Go to Google</a>
```

### JavaScript

Если поддерживается JavaScript, установите `window.location.href`.

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';" value="Go to Google" />
```

<sub>Перевод ответа «[How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2906586/564240)» [@Balusc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc).</sub>